Memory leak while executing PL/SQL function in Node.js
I have a node.js application which is executing PL/SQL function using oracledb npm library every 5 seconds (using node-cron). Setup is as follows.

nodejs 18.19.0
oracledb ^6.5.1

Basic oracledb functionality:
const pool = {};

function initDatabasePool() {
  oracledb.initOracleClient(); // use Thick client
  oracledb.dbObjectAsPojo = true; // plain old Javascript object

  const dbConfig = {
    user: config.oracleDB.user,
    password: config.oracleDB.password,
    connectString: config.oracleDB.connection,
  };

  return oracledb
    .createPool(dbConfig)
    .then(async (p) => {
      logger.info(`DB pool ${config.oracleDB.name} created`);
      pool[config.oracleDB.name] = p;

      // we want to test connection before executing jobs
      logger.info(`testing DB connection`);
      const testConnection = await getConnection(config.oracleDB.name);
      if (testConnection) {
        logger.info(`DB connection successful`);
        await testConnection.close();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logger.error(`Error initializing DB pool ${config.oracleDB.name}: ${err.stack}`);
      throw err;
    });
}

async function getConnection(dbName) {
  return await pool[dbName].getConnection();
}

async function execute(statement, variables) {
  let connection;
  let result;

  try {
    connection = await getConnection(config.oracleDB.name);
    result = await connection.execute(statement, variables);

    // if (result.outBinds.messageList) {
    //   result.outBinds.messageList = await lobToString(result.outBinds.messageList);
    // }

    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`${err.stack}`);

    throw err;
  } finally {
    if (connection) await connection.close();
  }
}

Command executed in a cron-job:
async function getMessagesForProcessing() {
  const statement = `
    BEGIN
      :returnValue := bgtw5.api_pcrf.f_set_messages_for_processing(y_message_list => :messageList);
      COMMIT;
    END;
  `;

  const variables = {
    returnValue: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.NUMBER },
    messageList: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: 'BGTW5.TC_PCRF_MESSAGE' },
  };

  const result = await db.execute(statement, variables);

  return {
    returnValue: result.outBinds.returnValue,
    messageList: result.outBinds.messageList,
  };
}

Oracle type BGTW5.TC_PCRF_MESSAGE is defined as a table of objects:
create or replace type to_pcrf_message is object (
  message_id      number,
  sn              varchar2(15),
  message_type    number,
  threshold_value number,
  actual_spend    number,
  threshold_limit number,
  event_date      date,

  constructor function to_pcrf_message return self as result
)

Right now there is no data fetched from the PL/SQL function, so that should not be a problem. The application is deployed on Openshift and I can see memory usage metrics gradually increasing over the last 24 hours:

I suspect the reason behind the memory leak is using Oracle collection as a variable type (line in code messageList: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: 'BGTW5.TC_PCRF_MESSAGE' } ) and maybe also using dbObjectAsPojo attribute. Because what I also tried is to only change messageList variable type to JSON (and change the implementation of the underlying PL/SQL function so that is returns JSON and not a collection of objects) and removing the dbObjectAsPojo attribute from pool initialization. In this case the memory usage was being steady under 100MB. So, yeah, I found a solution, but it's not the prettiest workaround  and I'd prefer to use PL/SQL collections instead of JSON.
Is there a way to keep using PL/SQL collection as output variable type without causing memory leak?

A memory leak on your client will have nothing at all to do with Oracle or PL/SQL. It'll be in your code. How you handle the client array that holds your collection output is a client-issue, not something Oracle manages. So it'll be a javascript memory management question, perhaps in Node.js.

(1). You're using Thick client, so make sure you grab the latest Instant Client libraries e.g. 23.5. (2). Also grab node-oracledb 6.6 since the developers will want you to test with this. (3). Regarding your workaround, I would be interested if it is faster. Objects can require a few round trips and be relatively slow.
